# Configuration parameters in web application (Java+Spring+Hibernate+Tapestry)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web, tapestry

I'm developing a web application and I need to save about 100 configuration parameters. What is the best solution?:

- Make a XML file and parse it for read the configuration.
- Make a table in database, and consult it for read the configuration.
- Another better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: are the conf. params. per application or per user?

Comment: but it can change during execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is usually done in this case is that the configuration parameters are stored in properties files that are then loaded by Spring.

In the event that you have parameters that can be changed during the execution of the application, then a fairly simple way to approach the problem would be to save them in the database

Comment: This way, Can I change a property value from the application?

Comment: No you cannot, those properties are loaded at deploy time and are not changeable. Do you need to change those properties?

Comment: Yes, for example, I need to choose if I want to save the max number of something, a superuser could change this parameter.

Comment: I thought a solution: You read the properties values and save all in memory (a java class) and if you change some value you modify it in memory and you override the properties file. Next time you run web application, Would it persist the values​​?